# Why dynamic routes need model file to be present in ember js

Tags: ember.js, routes, nested-routes

I was going through one of the Ember tutorial on lynda.com and I saw that the instructor defined a dynamic route as:

```
this.route('bookmarks', function() {
this.route('new');

this.route('edit', {
  path: '/edit/:bookmark_id'
 });
});
```

Now if I go to browser and type: "http://localhost:4200/bookmarks/new" then I can see my new route is getting loaded and i can see the content there. But if I try: "http://localhost:4200/bookmarks/edit/1" then ember does not show anything unless I create a model by name bookmarks. Can anyone tell why a model is needed for dynamic routes to get executed?

Comment: I guess it's because the implicit model hook of the route (supposing you didn't define it yet). You pass an id, so ember tries to get the fitting model.

Comment: and what's wrong on simply defining the model??

Comment: @Jeff There is nothing wrong in defining the model but I want to understand the dynamics behind it. In first case ember does not need any model to be defined but in case of dynamic segments, aka, routes, ember needs a model to be defined.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have `:bookmark_id` in route's path. It's called [dynamic segment](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_dynamic-segments)

Comment: one thing which I noticed few minutes back was if I return a model hook in route file and don't create a new model file, then also it works. So my guess is: in case of dynamic segments, ember needs model hook presence either from route.js or from model file for that route.

Comment: my gues would go further: Ember sets up a model on it's own and there it tries to use the model - which it can't find.